# Xcode, including a external reference folder in a build

Tags: xcode, build-process, libraries, project-reference, buildconfiguration

I have a folder located on my hard drive that is basically a library of handy classes i've created (file are .h and .cpp). I want to keep them external so I can reference them consistently from multiple ongoing projects.

I use add existing files and select the folder, adding it as a reference(blue folder)to my classes folder in xcode. When i attempt to access these files from project files i get a series of errors because obviously i have no idea what im doing. What steps do i need to take to ensure all my external files are included in the build?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I have a folder located on my hard drive that is basically a library of handy classes i've created (file are .h and .cpp).

Xcode doesn't automagically enumerate directory contents and produce static libraries, as folder references might imply. The easy way to manage this is to create a library which your other projects reference:

- Create a new Xcode Project
- Add a Static Library Target (note: this could possibly be another library type)
- Add your source files to the new project
- Add the .cpp files to the static library
- Add the new project to your existing app
- Add the library to the app's link phase
- Keep your static library in sync with the files to compile

That's just a summary; [This looks like a more detailed introduction.](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/)

Comment: Thanks for the response! This almost worked. I followed the tutorial and linked everything properly. The problem is that some of the files in my library are also dependent on the files in my project and are being thrown as not found, for example cocos2d.h and box2D.h. Was crossing my fingers both projects would just shake hands and play nice but this doesn't seem to be the case. In my situation does this mean I will not be able to use this method?

Comment: @user2033824 cocos2d and box2d are both third party libraries. assuming you're doing the obvious - just configure them as dependent static libraries as well. so say you have these 2 libs, your library and your app -- you have a dependency structure where your app depends on all 3 libraries and your library depends on these 2 libs. so you have a pretty clear dependency structure. your library needs to be able to locate its dependencies' headers (e.g. box2d), but your library should not link to box2d lib -- just tell your app target to do that.

Comment: @user2033824 IOW, you can use this method. your app should not compile the box2d sources if box2d provides a static library. it should just set the library as a dependency and link to it. reference these -- don't copy/duplicate work. there are some more advanced techniques to merge more complex dependencies, but this should work just fine for you right now. make sure you get the fundamentals before getting too fancy.

Comment: k ill give that a go. I wasn't copying any of it maliciously they're automatically included with cocos2d templates.

Comment: k, i have my set up, with project->mylibrary->b2dcc2dlib dependency. set up exactly like that tutorial. But both mylibrary and the b2dcc2dlib randomly can't find their own headers, and mylibrary still can't find the box2d and cocos2d headers. I'm getting the warning "b2dcc2dLib was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libb2dcc2dLib.a' because its architectures 'armv7' didn't contain all required architectures 'armv7 armv7s'" But looking at all target s in the project they default to 'armv7 armv7s'. What might i be doing wrong?

Comment: @user2033824 you will need to tell mylibrary where to find the headers (e.g. by defining `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` for the mylibrary target)

Comment: i've gone into all 3 project targets and set header_search_paths, user_header_search_paths and install_directory to $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR) and recursive. And set public_header_folder_path to $(TARGET_NAME). Still, headers are not being found, and the same implicit dependency warning.

Comment: @user2033824 `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)` is probably not what you want. it should be something like `../SomeLibrary/`. the value relative to the project path.

Comment: still can't get it to work. spent hours searching for hours and trying different things. turns out cocos2d isn't static library friendly. im just guna go for the primitive hard copy of the files. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: @user2033824 ok - strange that it would not have a friendly distribution :\